# Boolean algebra assistance

Tags: boolean

I'm confused. Is this the same?

```
!A && !B = !(A && B)?
```

Or is it `= !(A || B)`?

Comment: Why don't you try an example?  Just figure out the truth table for each of them.

Comment: It's what @mihaisimi says. DeMorgan's law. Generally speaking, you can find these things out by making a truth table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

!A && !B =  !(A || B)

This is one of "[DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)".
As a rule of thumb, I like to remember DeMorgan's laws with a quote I once read: "Do what you hate *or* find difficult; that is the sign of a strong person. Weak people only do what they like *and* find easy." (emphasis mine). This is a real-life application of DeMorgan's laws.

In general, you can find these things out by creating a truth table.